# Register for Window-closing event in C++/winrt

Tags: c++-winrt

How can I catch and potentially cancel a window closing event in C++/winrt? I've seen reference to this:

```
void OnClosing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
e.Cancel = !_allowClose;
}
```

(in the referenced example that is spelled '_e.Cancel' but I'm assuming that's a typo). In C++/winrt I would expect the above to translate to something like this:

```
void OnClosing(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const & sender, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const &  args)
{
args.Cancel(!_allowClose);
}
```

But _allowClose is not defined, .Cancel is not a member of args (it must be necessary to specify the args type), and most of all I don't know how to register for this event handler. There is of course just one window in this app, but I need to intercept any attempt to close that window via cntl-Q or the close box, in order to do certain things in the program and optionally cancel the close. Thanks.
[Update] I am told there is no WindowClosing event in winrt, which is a shame. According to the docs there is a WindowClosed event (following is a cut and paste):

```
struct WindowClosedEventHandler : winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown
{
   WindowClosedEventHandler(std::nulptr_t = nullptr) noexcept {}
   template <typename L> WindowClosedEventHandler(L lambda);
   template <typename F> WindowClosedEventHandler(F* function);
   template <typename O, typename M> WindowClosedEventHandler(O* object, M 
   method);
   void operator()(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::WindowClosedEventHandler const& 
   sender) const;
   };
```

But I don't know how to register for this event. Better by far would be an event letting me know before the close occurs, allowing a cancel - but even this much would help. It seems crucial to know that the window, the only window, is closing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Window Closing event in WinRT. You must be thinking of [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=netframework-4.7.1).

I'm pretty sure I found the sample code you're referring to, and it's obvious that _allowClose was defined as a global in that code and was not some hidden property of the class. It's literally the first line.

Comment: Well, the excerpt I saw did not include a declaration of that. But is it the case then that there is no way on earth to be notified that a winrt app is about to close? Wouldn't I want to be able to take care of business before that happens?

Comment: I must apologize - went back and found that excerpt again and indeed _allowClose had been declared at the top. Missed it. I will try reformulating my question in a separate entry - what I wanted was to be notified when the app was soon to depart. Maybe in winrt it doesn't really ever depart with out a force-quit, as on ios.